# jquery animate button problem help?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

http://jsfiddle.net/B2rdD/3/

I've Created 25 buttons using HTML and I have written jquery code such a way when user will rapidly click any of button all the buttons get glow at once but now the problem in above code is when i click a button for the first time it glows all 25 buttons but in second time it's not happening.

**my aim is if i click any of buttons quickly all buttons should glow then again for next button quickly**

can anybody help me to do this ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

EDITED for final fix: http://jsfiddle.net/B2rdD/29/

```
var $button = $(':button');

$button.click(function() {

    $button.stop(true,true).animate({

        'background-color': '#ADDFFF',
        opacity: 0.4

    }, 500, function() {

        $button.animate({

            'background-color': '#6DA6E2',
            opacity: 1

        }, 500) 

    });

});

$button.hover(function() {

    $(this).css({'background-color' : '#FFFFFF', 'color' : '#6DA6E2'});

}, function(){

    $(this).css({'background-color' : '#6DA6E2', 'color' : '#FFFFFF'});

});
```

First of all, I modified your inputs to all have unique id's, just for consistency's sake.  I also modified your css a little.  Now the jQuery I re-factored and added the hover technique.  First of all, you want to manage the animations.  You don't want them queuing up every time the user clicks a button, hence the `.stop(true,true)`.  The first true says to clear the queued animations and the second true tells it to jump to the end of the animation.  As far as the hover, that's just a straightforward `.hover()` method.

Comment: yo man where did u change the code ? where i did mistake in code ?

Comment: but problem is mouseover works only for first time time when i click 1 button then for secondtime it didn't show mouse over ?

Comment: ^ yeh i want that mouseover too be include

Answer (score 1):

Try this instead. Not sure what was going on with yours:

```
$(document).ready(
    function(){
        $(':button').click(

            function(){
                $(':button')
                    .animate({'background-color':'#ADDFFF',opacity: 0.4},500)
                    .animate({'background-color':'#ADDFFF',opacity: 1},500)


                    });


                 });
```